# function() assigned to attribute not executing in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to show a button based on the value in the Redux store. The button's attributes I want to pass dynamically.

```
const state = appStore.getState();
let opts = {};

if(state.bottomBar.tabName === 'TEST') {
  opts['btn1'] = `${this.btnText()}`; // Returns text
  opts['onBtn1Press'] = `${ () => this.addToTest() }`; // Returns function()
} else {
  opts['btn1'] = 'Testing';
  opts['onBtn1Press'] = `${ () => this.doSomething()}`;
}
```

I have passed the attributes as follows:

`<UiContainer {...opts}>`

In the `UiContainer` component another `Footer` component which contains the code as follows:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onBtn1Press()}  disabled={Btn1Disabled} >
  <View >                        
   <Text >{btn1}</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

if I print `ops` it prints as follows:

```
Object {
  "btn1": "TEST",
  "onBtn1Press": "function () {
            return _this4.addToTest();
          }",
}
```

When I click on the button it shows the *`_onBtn1Press()` is not a function*.

How can I fix it?

Regards,

Saneesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template

```
`${() => this.addToTest()}`
```

always return a string, that's why it has `"` around it when you print the value.

You want to defined a function instead

```
if(state.bottomBar.tabName === 'TEST') {
  opts['btn1'] = `${this.btnText()}`; // Returns text
  opts['onBtn1Press'] = () => this.addToTest(); // Returns function()
} else {
  opts['btn1'] = 'Testing';
  opts['onBtn1Press'] = () => this.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `aways returns a string` this is the key!

Comment: if possible, please consider to update the title according to the issue.